# Trying to filter a string for multiple values with REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match multiples groups from multiples lines according to a structured source string.

The string is formatted with one name per line, but with some other values, in this order:

- May have a number before the name starting each line;
- May have some junk separators between the number and the name;
- The name may have any character, including symbols as parentheses, apostrophes, etc;
- May have a code between parentheses with 3 or 4 letters after the name (don't bother with the possibility of the name having 3 or 4 letter between parenthesis, this will not happen)
- May have a asterisk at the end of line, before the break line.

I need to retrieve this 4 groups for each line. That is what I'm trying :

```
/^(\d+)?(?:[ \t]?[x:.=]?)[ \t]?(.+?)(?=[ \t]?(\(\w{3,4}\))?[ \t]?(\*))$/igm
```

To catch the number:

```
^(\d+)?
```

To clean the possible separators:

```
(?:[ \t]?[x:.=]?)
```

Filtering the space between each group:

```
[ \t]?
```

The name (and the rest):

```
(.+?(?=[ \t]?(\(\w{3,4}\))?[ \t]?(\*)?))
```

The problem is, obviously, with this last one. It's catching all together (groups 2, 3 and 4). As you can see, I'm trying the two last optional groups as positive lookaheads to separate them from the name.

What am I doing wrong or how would be the better way to achieve the result?

EDIT

String sample:

```
2 John Smith
3 Messala Oliveira (NMN) *
Mary Pop *
Joshua Junior (pMHH)
```

What I need:

```
[ "2", "John Smith", "", "" ],
[ "3", "Messala Oliveira", "(NMN)", "*" ],
[ "", "Mary Pop", "", "*" ],
[ "", "Joshua Junior", "(pMHH)", "" ],
```

Comment: Please provide example strings you wish to pass the test

Comment: `...([^ \t].*?)[ \t]?(\(\w{3,4}\)?[ \t]?(\*)?`?

Comment: @melpomene, thanks. I've tried without lookahead before, but I guess I was writting something wrong. Now it works as intented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the capturing groups that can be present or absent with optional non-capturing groups:

```
/^(?:(\d+)[ \t]*)?(.*?)(?:[ \t](\(\w{3,4}\)))?(?:[ \t](\*))?$/igm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bYvxSM/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(\d+)[ \t]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `(\d+)` - (Group 1) 1+ digits
  - `[ \t]*` - 0+ spaces or tabs (if `\s` is used, 0+ whitespaces)
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars other than linenbreaks symbols as few as possible
- `(?:[ \t](\(\w{3,4}\)))?` - an optional group matching

  - `[ \t]` - a space or tab
  - `(\(\w{3,4}\))` - Group 3 capturing a `(`, 3 or 4 word chars, `)`
- `(?:[ \t](\*))?` - another optional group matching a space or tab and capturing into Group 4 a `*` symbol.
- `$` - end of string.

If you test the strings separately, the `[ \t]` can be replaced with a simpler `\s`:

```js
var regex = /^(?:(\d+)\s*)?(.*?)(?:\s(\(\w{3,4}\)))?(?:\s(\*))?$/i;
var strs = ['2 John Smith','3 Messala Oliveira (NMN) *','Mary Pop *','Joshua Junior (pMHH)'];

for (var i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
    if ((m = regex.exec(strs[i])) !== null) {
        var res = [];
        if (m[1]) { 
          res.push(m[1]); 
        } else res.push("");
        res.push(m[2]);
        if (m[3]) { 
          res.push(m[3]); 
        } else res.push("");
        if (m[4]) { 
          res.push(m[4]); 
        } else res.push("");
    }
    console.log(res);
}
```